# Getting Full <iframe codes of multiple Pages

Tags: php, html, iframe

PHP newbie here

Long story short.

I have an account on adult site xhamster.com, I have 500 videos there, I need the 500

I have a list with the 500 videos URLs, I am a total newbie in PHP, but I am reading and learning for a solution for this for a week now and I think that is feasible.

Instead of going video by video manually, clicking the "Share or Embed" button, copying the code and pasting it on my excel file, I need a php solution.

In theory and from what I have read from now this are my thoughts:

- Make an array with all my  vids URLs
- Make a foreach loop so it goes to every URL
- Load the pages with this?? -- $dom = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($html);
- Use regex to get all iframe codes
- print, copy and paste

This is a sample iframe code found on the page in case it helps, that´s exactly what I need to put in the software:

```
 <iframe width="510" height="400" src="http://xhamster.com/xembed.php?video=2786368" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I am on the correct path doing what I stated above?

Can what I need even be done in php?

Thanks a lot for any input

Answer (score 0):

To actually get the pages contents you would utilize php's function [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) like so

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://hamstar.com/etc/');
```

Then create a new `DomDocument` and load `$html`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

afterwards you will be able to use common DOM methods like `getElementsByTagName` to find all iframes within the document.

```
$iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
```

`$iframes` now holds a DomNodeList over which items you might iterate and directly read the src attribute from like with [$domElement->getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)